# Rails 5 Multiple Devise Models using same controllers - architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, architecture

I currently have a rails 5 app that has 3 Devise Models and hence 3 separate logins. This is working well.

The challenge I am having is that all three models share the majority of the same resources, however with different authorisation levels. For example, one Devise model may be allowed new and create actions but not destroy etc etc.

Currently, I have controllers namespaced within each Devise model in controllers. So, for example, controllers > admins > same_resource_controller.rb and controllers > seats > same_resource_controller.rb. These files share a lot of the same code and it's creating unnecessary maintenance that I don't feel should be there.

So, If I was to use the controllers > same_resource_controller.rb at a top level I can foresee some fundamental issues:

**Authentication**, can I put a `authenticate_user!` in the controller that reads from application_controller:

```
def authenticate_user
  authenticate_admin! || authenticate_seat! || authenticate_client!
end
```

**current_user**, is it ok to have, and use, a method like this in the `application_controller.rb`?

```
def current_user
  current_admin || current_seat || current_client
end
```

The resulting potential issue is associating records, for example when querying, current_user.another_model.yet_another_model is not the same for and Admin as it is for a Seat.

I really like the idea of cutting down my controllers and tests and associated files by a third but I'm really unsure as to the correct architecture.

If anyone has been through the same or has any good links (I have struggled to find articles on dealing with controllers when multiple Devise models) I would really appreciate some help! Thank you!

Comment: Checkout [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models#6-fix-cross-model-visits-fancy-name-for-users-can-visit-admins-login-and-viceversa-and-mess-up-your-auth-tokens) to some idea

Answer (score 0):

Do they all care the same underlying table? At first sight, my question would be why not use a single resource, perhaps with `type` attribute if you need to flag the client, seat or admin. Are you using CanCan, Pundit, or another community-supported authorization framework?

Comment: They are currently using 3 different devise models that are associated differently to the same tables in the database. I'm using Pundit, and it has crossed my mind that I could use this by classname and allow authorisation that way? For example, if `current_user.class.to_s == "Seat"` then authorize. Obviously that would be in the model & policy file.